# history back() method close new opened tabs

Tags: javascript, html

My question is related to this post: [Javascript : History back() Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28342050/javascript-history-back-method)

I want to implement a "back" button on my website. But lets imagine the page was opened in a new tab.

Is there a way to close the window, if the browser history is empty?

I am kinda struggling to connect the history.back() and window.close() function but that's all I ve got to do, isn't it?

appreciate your help!

Comment: Every tab (or window) has it's own history object, which is empty at the time you're first opening the tab.

Comment: See my comment on @Titulum answer. If you're not opening the window using `window.open()`, you're not going to to be able to close it using `window.close()`

Comment: I would suggest you to create your own history object, so whenever you opened any tab/window add it in your object and when user press back or next then close/open window.

Comment: The above suggestion will only work, if user is navigating with your website's buttons, otherwise browsers back/next will be different for window as @Teemu said

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3588420/2764486), it is not possible to definitely determine whether there are still browser history entries or not. Thus, @Titulum's solution should work but could fail depending on the browser implementation of the History API.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a method like this:

```js
function closeWindowIfHistoryIsEmpty() {
  if (window.history.length === 0) {
    window.close();
  } else {
    window.history.back();
  }
}
```

Comment: Technically this will work, but OP needs to keep in mind that `window.close()` will only close windows that were opened by `window.open()` :  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close

Comment: Ok it is as you said. The code is technically working but, as I am not using the window.open() function, it is not working as expected...